# Is there a way I can stop the flashing as one ng-show takes over from another?

Tags: angularjs

I am using this code to show a different icon depending on the status. But as it moves from one to another there's a flash where it seems neither shows up. Is there some way I could fix this or simplify my method:

```
            <span class="fa fa-circle-o fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.NotSet"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-unlock fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.Clean"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-wrench fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.Dirty"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.Saving"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-check fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.Saved"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
            <span class="fa fa-warning fw"
                  ng-show="row.statusId == Status.SaveError"
                  style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
```

Comment: Can't you just use `ng-class` for that? Still it seems to be the case of `row.statusId` going to some value not mentioned here long enough for `$digest` to be fired; it's up to you (and the business logic behind your site) to decide what to do next.

Comment: @raina77ow - I'm not sure how I would use ng-class as it's a choice of any one of those status values

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, the syntax seems to be rather straight-forward: `ng-class="{'fa-circle-o': row.statusId === Status.NotSet, 'fa-unlock': row.statusId === Status.Clean, ...` and so on. Might be helpful to organize these `row.statusId` checks into functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@raina77ow is correct..use ng-class here...it can accept a function...here is some pseudo code

html:

```
<div id="rows-container" ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <span ng-class="getStatus(row.statusId)" style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
</div>
```

js:

```
$scope.getClassBasedOnStatus = function(statusId) {
  switch (statusId) {
    case 'Status.NotSet':
      return 'fa fa-circle-o fw';
      break;
    case 'Status.Clear':
      return 'fa fa-unlock fw';
      break;
    case 'Status.Dirty':
      return 'fa fa-wrench fw';
      break;
    // etc...
  }
}
```

check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L1Lshjvz/1/

Comment: I have about 500 rows. Would it still work okay with that many. Also could I put that into an inline case statement ?

Comment: were those spans in a repeat? I suppose you could, I think it's cleaner to use a function

Comment: yes they are inside a repeat.  with each row having all those spans

Comment: Ok, yeah of course..so instead of all those spans, you use one span and `ng-class` to pass the `row.statusId` to the function like I am doing.

Comment: I added a fiddle link with an example..I am using static data and only 3 rows, but you should get the idea. If you change the statusId in the rows array and hit run, you'll see the class update

Answer (score 1):

I have found [`ng-switch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) works the best in this case.

You can use it like:

```
    <div class="the-parent" ng-switch="row.statusId">
        <span class="fa fa-circle-o fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.NotSet"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-unlock fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.Clean"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-wrench fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.Dirty"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-cloud-upload fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.Saving"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-check fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.Saved"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
        <span class="fa fa-warning fw"
              ng-switch-when="Status.SaveError"
              style="padding-left: 0.3rem;"></span>
    </div>
```